# Update XML element text with PHP

Tags: php, xml

I'm trying to update XML element text based upon a form submission. It is a userdatabase and im using the user's password as a reference to update their user id. The passwords all all unique so I thought it would be an easy element to reference. However whenever I attempt to edit a UID it fails and sends me to my error page I created if the function fails. Im not sure where I went wrong any assistance would be great.

**Update UID Function**

```
function updateUID($pass, $file, $new)
{
    $xml = new DOMDocument();
    $xml->load($file);
    $record = $xml->getElementsByTagName('UniqueLogin');
    foreach ($record as $person) {
        $password_id = $person->getElementsByTagName('Password')->item(0)->nodeValue;
        //$person_name=$person->getElementsByTagName('name')->item(0)->nodeValue;
        if ($password_id == $password) {
            $id_matched = true;
            $updated  = $xml->createTextNode($new);
            $person->parentNode->replaceChild($person, $updated);
            
            break;
        }
    }
    if ($id_matched == true) {
        if ($xml->save($file)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    
}
```

**Code that calls the function**

```
session_start();
include_once "includes/functions.inc.php";
include_once "includes/jdbh.inc.php";
include_once "includes/dbh.inc.php";
include_once "includes/ftpconn2.inc.php";
$file = $_SESSION['fileNameXML'];
if (file_exists($file)) {
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $pass = $_POST['id'];
        //$uid = $_SESSION['userid'];
        $new  = $_POST['uid'];
        //$entry = getUsername($jconn, $uid)."&nbsp;deleted a server ban for".$name;
        //if (isset($_GET['confirm'])) {
            if (updateUID($pass, $file, $new)) {
                //createLogEntry($conn, $uid, $entry);
                if (1 < 2) { //This is intentional to get around the $message varible below that is not required. 
                    $message = $affectedRow . " records inserted";
                    try {
                        $ftp_connection = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
                        if (false === $ftp_connection) {
                            throw new Exception("Unable to connect");
                            
                        }
                        $loggedIn = ftp_login($ftp_connection, $ftp_user, $ftp_password);
                        if (true === $loggedIn) {
                            //echo "Success!";
                        } else {
                            throw new Exception('unable to log in');
                        }
                        $local_file1  = "HostSecurity.xml";
                        $remote_file1 = "HostSecurity.xml";
                        if (ftp_put($ftp_connection, $local_file1, $remote_file1, FTP_BINARY)) {
                            //echo "Successfully written to $local_file\n";
                            
                        } else {
                            echo "There was a problem";
                        }
                        ftp_close($ftp_connection);
                        header("location: ../serverPasswords.php");
                    }
                    catch (Exception $e) {
                        echo "Failure:" . $e->getMessage();
                    }
                }
                header("location: ../serverPasswords.php");
            } else {
                header("location: ../serverPasswords.php?e=UIDNPD");
            }
    } else {
        echo "id missing";
    }
} else {
    echo "$file missing";
}
```

```
<Unique_Logins>
<UniqueLogin>
  <UID>AA23GHRDS657FGGRSF126</UID>
  <Password>iMs0Az2Zqh</Password>
</UniqueLogin>
<UniqueLogin>
  <UID>AA23GSDGFHJKDS483FGGRSF126</UID>
  <Password>Ab7wz77kM</Password>
</UniqueLogin>
</Unique_Logins>
```

Comment: Can you update your question and add the error message?

Comment: It redirects to the script in the thrid from last else statement. There isn't any error persay
header("location: ../serverPasswords.php?e=UIDNPD");

Comment: In your `updateUID` function, where is `$password` defined before using in `if ($password_id == $password)` ??? The function is passed 3 arguments - the first is presmably the one you want to use but is simply called `$pass`

Comment: Also - why not simply use an XPath rather than the loop?

Comment: That function also only returns a value under a very specific condition so basing a fork in logic on that seems erroneous

Comment: How about XSLT based solution?

Comment: Don't use `$nodeValue` (broken escaping) but `$textContent`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue was caused by the undeclared variable `$password` in the logic test and the fact that the function never returns an alternative value if things go wrong.

As per the comment regarding `XPath` - perhaps the following might be of interest.

```
<?php

    $pass='xiMs0Az2Zqh';
    $file='logins.xml';
    $new='banana';



    function updateUID( $pass=false, $file=false, $new=false ){
        if( $pass & $file & $new ){
            $dom = new DOMDocument();
            $dom->load( $file );
            
            # attempt to match the password with this XPath expression
            $expr=sprintf( '//Unique_Logins/UniqueLogin/Password[ contains(.,"%s") ]', $pass );

            $xp=new DOMXPath( $dom );
            $col=$xp->query( $expr );
            
            # We have a match, change the UID ( & return a Truthy value )
            if( $col && $col->length===1 ){
                $xp->query('UID', $col->item(0)->parentNode )->item(0)->nodeValue=$new;
                return $dom->save( $file );
            }
        }
        # otherwise return false
        return false;
    }
    
    
    $res=updateUID( $pass, $file, $new );
    
    if( $res ){
        echo 'excellent';
    }else{
        echo 'bogus';
    }

?>
```

Comment: It's still not working it keeps returning the bogus option

Comment: I actually found out what the issue was, apparently the file location was not pointed to the right place.

Comment: in the above the xml file is in the same working directory as the running script - should have mentioned that perhaps, but no indication of file paths in the question because of the session variable. If the file location was a factor in your code too you would still need to have a default return value of false to catch situations where the user does not supply correct pwd

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not clear on exactly what's wrong, but if I understand you correctly, try making these changes in your code and see if it works:

```
#just some dummy values
$oldPass = "Ab7wz77kM";
$newUid  = "whatever";

$record = $xml->getElementsByTagName('UniqueLogin');
foreach ($record as $person) {
    $password_id = $person->getElementsByTagName('Password');
    $user_id     = $person->getElementsByTagName('UID');
    if ($password_id[0]->nodeValue == $oldPass) {
        $user_id[0]->nodeValue = $newUid;
    }
}
```